# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1)?

Tags: android

I am creating a table. Android studio is giving sqliteException in create table query. I couldn't find out what is mistake in this create query. Any help is appreciated. I know it says there is problem where i have my "KEY_UNIQUE" field but this field looks like ok to me. I have tried to remove spaces, commas and i am doing these kind of stuff for like 2 or 3 hours but this error does not seems to be solved.

```
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "lifecare";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_UNIQUE = "unique";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String KEY_QUALIFICATION = "qualification";
    public static final String KEY_SPECIALITY = "speciality";
    public static final String KEY_ROLE = "role";

public sqlHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +
                "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_UNIQUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_QUALIFICATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_SPECIALITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_ROLE + " TEXT NOT NULL );");
    }
```

Here is logcat.

```
ATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.lenovo.lifecare, PID: 24508
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE lifecare(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, unique TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, qualification TEXT NOT NULL, speciality TEXT NOT NULL, role TEXT NOT NULL );
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:892)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:503)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1773)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
                                                                             at com.example.lenovo.lifecare.sqlHelper.onCreate(sqlHelper.java:96)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                             at com.example.lenovo.lifecare.sqlHelper.insert(sqlHelper.java:123)
                                                                             at com.example.lenovo.lifecare.insertquery.insert(insertquery.java:73)
                                                                             at com.example.lenovo.lifecare.insertquery$1.onClick(insertquery.java:42)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5107)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `UNIQUE` is a [keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Either quote it everywhere you use it as a column name, or just call it something else.

Comment: Thanx alot bro.